# simpleXML access namespace with same name

Tags: php, xml

I'm pretty new to XML namespaces and searching on the title show some people having the same problem, but somehow it doesn't work for me.

XML situation:

```
<abc:documents xmlns:abc="http://www.someurl.com/xml/abc/dtd" count="1">
<def:doc xmlns:def="http://www.someurl.com/xml/def/dtd">
<def:meta>
    <def:hello-world>hi there</def:hello-world>
</def:meta>
<def:serial-item>
    <ghi xmlns="http://www.someurl.com/xml/ja/dtd" docsubtype="fla" xml:lang="en" version="5.1">
        <item-info>
            <helloworld>hi there</helloworld>
        </item-info>
    </ghi>    
</def:serial-item>
</def:doc>
</abc:documents>
```

When I do this:

```
$xml      = new SimpleXMLElement('<abc:documents xmlns:abc="http://www.someurl.com/xml/abc/dtd" count="1">...THE ABOVE XML...</abc:documents>');
$doc      = $xml->children('def', TRUE);
$data     = $doc->children('def', TRUE);
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo $data->asXML();
```

It only shows the content of def:meta

But when I do: `var_dump(count($data))` it shows correctly (2)

So one would expect to do:

```
foreach($data as $dataPiece){
    echo $dataPiece->asXML();
    echo '--------------';
}
```

But is just shows the content of def:meta...

**So the question is: How can I go through: `<ghi>`**

Comment: `So the question is: How can I go through...`? Go through what?

Comment: @AmalMurali ghi <ghi>